# Link to formatted revisions when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

The rendered output for the diff isn't quite the same as what is viewed in the post, for instance code blocks do not scroll horizontally, and some formatting is compressed due to the smaller width available.

For instance when looking at the [following review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/720150) it's not easy to see the formatting change to reduce the horizontal scrolling. It would be useful if the edits provided links to the formatted pages, namely https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12623555/4 and https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12623555/3.

These links should support standard methods to open in a new tab.