# Word-wrap unhelpful when reviewing code-block edits

Tags: feature-request, review, diff

The lack of horizontal scrolling in side-by-side diffs of code-blocks during the review process often makes the process somewhat challenging.  Here is an example that prompted me to finally speak up about this.

[image: Word-wrapped diff of code block]

Now, I expect that horizontal scrolling has probably been disabled so that the reviewer doesn't miss important changes, but I believe this does more harm than good.  Sure, I can see all the changes side-by-side, but it's not at all easy to see whether the edit is an improvement.

In fact, the edit on the above question was approved ([by a single user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2653320)).  If you [look at the revision stack for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18048311/revisions) it's still not clear whether the edit was an improvement.

In normal display of a question or answer, horizontal scrolling in code-blocks is enabled.  If I want to examine the layout before and after, I need to drill into the revision stack and edit individual revisions in order to see a preview.  Because I can no longer see the actual changes as a diff, the whole review process is undermined.

May I recommend that horizontal scrollbars can be enabled on code-block reviews?  Even better would be a check-box that allows me to toggle horizontal scrolling and/or enable preview without diff.

Note that, by the time I finished writing this question, Meta had finally provided a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148584/200806) in the sidebar, but it appears to have had little attention.  So please accept this more fully-formed question as a follow-up.

Comment: Another [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126075/200806) showed up only after posting.  I wonder why these don't seem to show up in the searches that I do prior to posting.